# jQuery idSelector.bind() method is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I want to bind a button with an event of mouseover. While I hover the mouse over the button the style is doing it's part but on mouseout the changed style is not removing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $('#btnSubmit').bind('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {

             if (event.type = 'mouseover') {
                $(this).addClass('ButtonStyle');
            }
            else  {
                $(this).removeClass('ButtonStyle');
            }
        });
    });
</script>


 <style>
    .ButtonStyle
    {
        background-color:red;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to us mouse leave function

Try something like this

Code:

```
 $('#btnSubmit').bind('mouseover', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('ButtonStyle');
    })
    .bind('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ButtonStyle');
    });
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: can you tell me how can i use this style class to all the buttons in a page

Comment: use a common class to the button for example 'btn-hover-common' and replace the #btnSubmit in above code with '.btn-hover-common'. and then it will work for every button.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply  do it **ONLY** with css:

```css
.btn:hover{
background-color:red;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">try hover me</button>
```

**OR separate
 it to tow functions:**

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $('#btnSubmit').bind('mouseover', function (event) {
                $(this).addClass('ButtonStyle');
        });
        $('#btnSubmit').bind('mouseout', function (event) {
                $(this).removeClass('ButtonStyle');
        });

    });
```

```css
    .ButtonStyle
    {
        background-color:red;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSubmit">Try hover me</button>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: can you tell me how can i use this style class to all the buttons in a page

Comment: use class not id and use each function

Comment: each function is not really required for binding the events to the DOM elements

Comment: simply add class to all buttons `btn` and simply use the css code with `:hover`

Comment: happy to help :)